# Making a take function myself

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to make a `take` function myself, but this appears to be giving a stack overflow, any idea what may be causing it?

```
(defn my-take-plus [n Lst LstAcc count]
  (let [LstVec (into [] Lst)]
    (cond (= count n) LstAcc
    :else 
      (do
         (conj LstAcc (first LstVec))
         (inc count)
         (my-take-plus n (apply list(rest LstVec)) LstAcc count)
      )
   )
 )
)


(defn my-take [n Lst]
  (my-take-plus n Lst [] 0)
)
```

Comment: Your calls to `inc` and `conj` aren't doing anything since you're throwing away what they return. They don't mutate their arguments. You might want to work on a simpler project first to get a hang of immutability.

Comment: @Carcigenicate would it work if i increment and conj in the recursion call?

Comment: Yes. Try it out. Q

Comment: @Carcigenicate I did it, and It works, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

also, there is one more 'clojurish' way to do this:

```
(defn my-take [n data]
  (when (and (pos? n) (seq data))
    (lazy-seq
     (cons (first data)
           (my-take (dec n) (rest data))))))
```

this one is lazy, and also prevents stack overflow.. Moreover, as far as i remember, the `clojure.core/take` is implemented in a similar way

Comment: The [core function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2853) wraps everything in the `lazy-seq`: for maximum laziness, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a `loop/recur` strategy so that Clojure does tail-call optimization (TCO) to prevent a Stack Overflow.

```
(defn take' [n coll]
      (loop [n    n
             acc  []
             coll coll]
        (cond
          (empty? coll) acc
          ((comp not pos?) n) acc
          :else (recur (dec n) (conj acc (first coll)) (rest coll)))))
```

In your example, I would've considered using an `if` since you only had to conditional branches. `cond` is generally used more like a `case` statement.

Comment: Suggest you replace *can attempt to do some* with *does*. As I'm sure you're aware (though OP may not be), TCO is guaranteed with `recur`. Might be worth mentioning too that you lose laziness. By the way, I like the way you shadow the function arguments in the loop: prevents erroneous references to the former, a blunder I've too often committed.